# Using Zxing Library with Jetpack compose

Tags: zxing, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to implement qr scanner using zxing library. For this, i have added a button on screen, and on click of it, i am launching scanner as below

```
Button(
        onClick = {
            val intentIntegrator = IntentIntegrator(context)
            intentIntegrator.setPrompt(QrScanLabel)
            intentIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(true)
            intentIntegrator.initiateScan()
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Text(
            text = QrScanLabel
        )
    }
```

but, it launches an intent, which expects `onActivityResult` method to get back the results. And Jetpack compose uses `rememberLauncherForActivityResult` like below

```
val intentLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()
    ) {
        if (it.resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            return@rememberLauncherForActivityResult
        }
        ...
    }
```

but how do we integrate both things together here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I make a provisional solution with same library:
Gradle dependencies:

```
implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.1.0') { transitive = false }
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0'
```

My new Screen with jetpack compose and camera capture, that works for my app:

```
@Composable
fun AdminClubMembershipScanScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var scanFlag by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    val compoundBarcodeView = remember {
        CompoundBarcodeView(context).apply {
            val capture = CaptureManager(context as Activity, this)
            capture.initializeFromIntent(context.intent, null)
            this.setStatusText("")
            capture.decode()
            this.decodeContinuous { result ->
                if(scanFlag){
                    return@decodeContinuous
                }
                scanFlag = true
                result.text?.let { barCodeOrQr->
                    //Do something and when you finish this something
                    //put scanFlag = false to scan another item
                    scanFlag = false
                }
                //If you don't put this scanFlag = false, it will never work again.
                //you can put a delay over 2 seconds and then scanFlag = false to prevent multiple scanning 
                
            }
        }
    }

    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier,
        factory = { compoundBarcodeView },
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, its helpful. just wanted to ask if its specific to barcode view or can be used for qr too? @jose-pose-s

Comment: Hi @bharat-kumar! Yep this code works with barcode and qr.

Comment: i used above code, its scanning fine, but even after navigating to new compose screen, its still active, and scanning the qr if camera faces one. how can i avoid that?

Comment: @bharat-kumar You have at least 3 options:
1º Before navigate turn `scanFlag = true` and prevent to scan in background but camera is ready if you come back.
2º  Pause camera with  `compoundBarcodeView .pause()` but to start again you must call `compoundBarcodeView .decodeContinuous {`  this will be complex in functional programming.
3º Option change navigation system, if you don´t need more camera then use `navController.navigate("route") -> route{ popUpTo(route){ saveState = true} launchSingleTop = true restoreState = true }` to remove this screen and navigat to destination you want.

Comment: Hi @Mehdi.ncb I edit my code, you shoud use scanFlag = false to enable scan again, is a flag to prevent múltiple scanning, of course if you put always to false will scan same code múltiple times, if you wan´t you can scan wait 10 seconds and then put scanFlag = false for example.

Comment: Hey @BharatKumar I would like to ask if you have some qr code generator for jetpack compose. Every tutorial I find is using kotlin thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @bigQ, i just had used the qr code scanner and not generator.

Comment: @bharat-kumar you can use a disposable effect in order to call resume() and pause() whenever your composable enters or exits the composition respectively. see my answer bellow for more details on this

Answer (score 15):

Since `zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0` there is a `ScanContract`, which can be used directly from Compose:

```kotlin
val scanLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ScanContract(),
    onResult = { result -> Log.i(TAG, "scanned code: ${result.contents}") }
)

Button(onClick = { scanLauncher.launch(ScanOptions()) }) {
    Text(text = "Scan barcode")
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Addendum to the accepted answer**

This answer dives into the issues commented on by @Bharat Kumar and @Jose Pose S
in the accepted answer.

I basically just implemented the accepted answer in my code and then added the following code just after the defining `compundBarCodeView`

```
DisposableEffect(key1 = "someKey" ){
    compoundBarcodeView.resume()
    onDispose {
        compoundBarcodeView.pause()
    }
}
```

this makes sure the scanner is only active while it is in the foreground and unbourdens our device.

**TL;DR**

In escence even after you scan a QR code successfully and leave the scanner screen, the barcodeview will "haunt" you by continuing to scan from the backstack. which you usually dont want. And even if you use a boolean flag to prevent the scanner from doing anything after the focus has switched away from the scanner it will still burden your processor and slow down your UI since there is still a process constantly decrypting hi-res images in the background.

Answer (score 1):

I have a problem, I've the same code as you, but i don't know why it's showing me a black screen

**Code AddProduct**

```
@ExperimentalPermissionsApi
@Composable
fun AddProduct(
    navController: NavController
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var scanFlag by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    val compoundBarcodeView = remember {
        CompoundBarcodeView(context).apply {
            val capture = CaptureManager(context as Activity, this)
            capture.initializeFromIntent(context.intent, null)
            this.setStatusText("")
            capture.decode()
            this.decodeContinuous { result ->
                if(scanFlag){
                    return@decodeContinuous
                }
                scanFlag = true
                result.text?.let { barCodeOrQr->
                    //Do something

                }
                scanFlag = false
            }
        }
    }

    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = { compoundBarcodeView },
    )

}
```

Comment: you can check if the app has camera permission or not.

Comment: Yes I have the permission, I will put the code in the edit

Comment: put this code :- `this.resume()` before or after capture.decode() and check if that helps.

Comment: It has solved my problem, but now I encounter another problem, the app is scanning multiple time the barCode when I'm putting the camera in front of the code

Comment: Hi @Mehdi.ncb I edit my code, you shoud use `scanFlag = false` to enable scan again, is a flag to prevent múltiple scanning, of course if you put always to false will scan same code múltiple times, if you wan´t you can scan wait 10 seconds and then put `scanFlag = false` for example.

Comment: Okay, thank you, you helped me a lot !!! I'll text you if I have another problem that I can't solve