# How to navigate to compose screen from activity or fragment?

Tags: kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, state-management

I have navigated from a Jetpack Compose screen to an activity using an intent, but then I am struggling to go back to a Compose screen. So what is the best way to navigate back to compose by not killing an activity using destroy method -> finish()

I tried using finish(), but it destroys the state.

Comment: What do you mean by "Jetpack compose screen"? Compose UI cannot just exist on itself, it lives inside activity. So you can either replace content of the activity you are in with compose content, or navigate to different activity with compose content...

Comment: My application is using compose screens, and it only has one activity. which is the main activity for the app, so navigating within compose screens is easy as I can use composable navigation. But I had to add a legacy library as part of the project and is using activities not compose, so i can navigate to activity but i can not navigate back to compose.... @JanBína

Comment: Well in this case, the correct approach is definitely to `finish` the activity you opened, which will get you back to your compose activity. This should not destroy state of your compose activity. At the same time, this is something that the external activity should do... what does that library do?

Comment: So is a barcode scanner library from zxing, and is not supporting Compose. It looks like they have discontinued support to the library, and from that activity I want to pass the barcode back to my compose screen and assign it to a TextField.  @JanBína

Comment: @JanBína Thank you for trying to help me out, I think I didn't do my research roughly. This helped to solve my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/68244649/8629290