# Inflating zxing library into an AndroidView from jetpack compose causes infinite loop

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, qr-code, zxing

I am trying to implement a CompoundBarcodeView/DecoratedBarcodeView into my compose view like this:

```
@Composable
fun ScannerView(modifier: Modifier) {
    AndroidView(
        factory = { contextAndroidView ->
            CompoundBarcodeView(contextAndroidView)
        },
        modifier = modifier,
    )
}
```

But it cause an infinite loop in my app with logs saying that my app is inflating and initialising multiple times the DecoratedBarcodeView.

I've tried multiples other setups for DecoratedBarcodeView, but had the same issue each time. I'm sharing the most simple code that causes the issue. The most coherent other way to make it work was this one that I tried:

```
val compoundBarcodeView = remember { CompoundBarcodeView(context) }
    LaunchedEffect(compoundBarcodeView) {
        compoundBarcodeView.apply {
            val capture = CaptureManager(context as Activity, this)
            capture.initializeFromIntent(context.intent, null)
            this.setStatusText("")
            capture.decode()
            this.decodeContinuous { result ->

            }
        }
    }
    AndroidView(
        factory = { contextAndroidView ->
            compoundBarcodeView
        },
        modifier = modifier,
    )
    DisposableEffect(key1 = "someKey" ){
        compoundBarcodeView.resume()
        onDispose {
            compoundBarcodeView.pause()
        }
    }
```

But still faced the infinite loop problem with logs:

```
at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView.initialize(DecoratedBarcodeView.java:91)
                                                                                                      at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView.<init>(DecoratedBarcodeView.java:69)
                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native method)
                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1010)
                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
                                                                                                      at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:27735)
                                                                                                      at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView.initialize(DecoratedBarcodeView.java:91)
                                                                                                      at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView.<init>(DecoratedBarcodeView.java:69)
```

I've tried the same code that this stack thread: [Using Zxing Library with Jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68139363/using-zxing-library-with-jetpack-compose)
But still facing the same issue.

I'm calling the ScannerView from this view that's inside a bottomview:

```
@Composable
fun TransactionView() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
        Text(text ="Transaction View")
        ScannerView(
            modifier = Modifier
        )
    }
}
```

Does someone has faced this problem and knows how to resolve the issue?